# Set membership test not working (Python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, set

I have the following file, my_animals.txt, with a list of strings:

```
cat
dog
bear
wolf
flamingo
parrot
```

I'm using Python to read the file into a set with each line in my_animals.txt as an element of the set:

```
my_animals = set()

# read in file
with open('my_animals.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for animal in f:
        my_animals.add(animal.rstrip("\n"))

# check for membership
if "cat" in my_animals:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Unfortunately, my membership check is returning `False`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `print(my_animals)` to make sure it contains what you expected?

Comment: Why are you reading the file in binary mode?

Comment: yes. it returns expected output

Comment: because the real file i'm working with is 1GB

Comment: What does `print my_animals` print?

Comment: "because the real file i'm working with is 1GB" - have you tested that the *input in your question* actually reproduces the error you're having with the 1GB file?

Comment: it prints: set(['flamingo', 'parrot', 'dog', 'bear', 'cat', 'wolf'])

Comment: @user2357112 yes I've tested with the inputs I'm using in this question. Doesn't work

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your error. I think there's probably something important going on you didn't show us.

Comment: @Brinley Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yup. File had to be opened in text mode. And had to use .rstrip() instead of .rstrip("\n")

Comment: @Brinley Ah I see. Quick question. Are you on windows? Also, python2?

Comment: Linux box and python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach to what you're currently doing. First, open your file in text mode:

```
with open('my_animals.txt', 'r') as f:
```

Also, use `my_animals.add(animal.rstrip())`, the newline will automatically be stripped along with any other whitespace character. This is useful especially if you're on Windows, for example, where a line is delimited by `\r\n`.

Comment: The `print` syntax says it's Python 2, as does `rstrip("\n")` not throwing a TypeError, so it's *probably* not a bytes/unicode mismatch.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe it should be `my_animals.add(animal.rstrip())` then?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written is correct, and as the comments mention you can remove the 'b' so as not to read the file in binary mode. You can test with a smaller file to ensure this is the case.

As an aside: If your file is 1GB (as you mentioned in the comments), please don't load the whole thing into a set unless you're sure you have enough memory to do it!